# how to prove that from $(a+2023d > 2022b+c)$ & $(c+2023f > 2022d+e)$ goes $a+2023f>2022b+e$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given

$(a+2023d > 2022b+c)$ AND

$(c+2023f > 2022d+e)$

Prove:

$a+2023f>2022b+e$

I've been trying to think about it for a while but nothing comes to my head, I've also tried to substitute numbers where it wouldn't be true, but again nothing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hint:  $A>B$ and $C>D$ implies $A+C>B+D$.

Comment: It's easy to prove $a+2023f+d>2022b+e,$ but I'm not even sure your inequality is true.

Comment: Need to express the domain of variables. For example could a, b, c =0?  are they all integers? etc.

Comment: This is not true, as written.

Let $a=0.5, b=c=d=1, f=\frac{2022.1}{2023}.$

Comment: An integer counterexample as $$a=1, b=c=d=e=3\cdot 2023,  f=3\cdot 2022+1.$$

Comment: Where did you get this problem? Either the original is wrong, or you have entered it here wrong.

Comment: The problem statement is valid for some integer values. See my brute force attempt:https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ub6zAq